# Replacing text in a string

Tags: c#, string

I need to replace all instances of `""` with `"null"` in my string.

I was going to use

```
 result.Replace("", "");
```

but I cant seem to find a way to specify the two ".

Comment: As a note that will only be obvious to those that already know it:  `string.Replace` _returns_ a string and does not make the change to `result` itself (in the example code).

Comment: Interesting. I headed straight for string.Empty, but that doesn't work. You can't say result.Replace(string.Empty, "null").

Comment: are you trying to replace the string with `null` as in *the* `null` or are you trying to get `"null"` as the string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the \ escape character:

```
result.Replace("\"\"", "\"null\"");
```

Comment: I don't imagine they want "null" stored, at least the question doesn't read that way.

Comment: Yes I did want null inside the quotes

Answer (score 14):

Escape quotes:

```
result.Replace("\"\"", "\"null\""); // will return a new string
```

**[edit]** Forgot the quotes in the replacement.